# Deploy API with DotNet Core to a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS

Tags: iis, .net-core

I am trying to follow a very simple TodoApi tutorials found on here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

I could run it as standalone on my local box using

```
dotnet run <ApplicationName>
```

Quick test using Postman showed the standalone application is running fine on my local computer. However, when I tried to "deploy" the application to my Windows Server 2008 R2 (I have installed DotNetCore SDK and DotNetCore WindowsHosting in there), I got this error:

[image]

By "deploy", I meant xcopying the folder. So my questions here are two folds:

1) Is there a guideline/instruction of how to deploy a standalone api with dotnet core to a different windows server, the prerequisites for the server to be able to host such api application?

2) Is there a guideline to deploy the api to IIS?

Thanks,

Comment: check the dotnet versions between the local computer and sever dotnet --version

Comment: @JayabaskarRajagopal: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems to compile but when I used postman to quickly send a request to the server, the request was never received and the blue sending button showed that it keeps waiting for some response/reaction from the server.

Comment: @JayabaskarRajagopal: Also, my goal is to just deploy the binary code to the server only, not xcopy the whole folder with code. How is it possible to do that?

Comment: i think you can just use the dotnet command to run the dll. Like  "dotnet myapp.dll" this will start your app.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-run. I am sorry not very familiar with windows server we are using docker images of dotnet core apps to deploy them on linux servers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much researches and head banging against the wall, I've finally found an great article from Rick Stralh that detailed how an Asp.Net Core application should be published and hosted with IIS. I found this article highly, extremely useful and answered to all my questions. I think I would like to share in case others may run into the same issue as myself. Thank you, Rick!!

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS#'Running'IIS

Comment: But did it solve your initial problem? 
What's the outcome of the questions you shared? Actually question 1) has two interesting questions inside...